# Differential equation using dynamicsymbols in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, differential-equations

In Sympy, I tried to solve a differential equation like this:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols
x = dynamicsymbols('x')
diffeq = Eq(x(t).diff(t), x(t))
dsolve(diffeq, x(t))
```

But that returns

```
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8a45d7148b24> in <module>()
      1 x = dynamicsymbols('x')
----> 2 diffeq = Eq(x(t).diff(t), x(t))
      3 dsolve(diffeq, x(t))

TypeError: 'x' object is not callable
```

As far as I understand, `dynamicsymbols` creates a function of t, so how do I use it in a differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sympy docs are a bit confusing](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/functions.html) as the output of

```
print(x)
```

is in fact

```
x(t)
```

However that doesn't mean are supposed to call `x(t)`:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.vector import dynamicsymbols
x = dynamicsymbols('x')
diffeq = Eq(diff(x, Symbol('t')), x)
dsolve(diffeq, x)   # Eq(x(t), C1*exp(t))
```